# MySQL get count from two related tables

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL and database server and I have two tables one is for **customer** and another for **customer_contacts**.
Here are the table structures:

```
customer(
    id(pk, ai)
    name
    email
)
```

and

```
customer_contacts(
    id(ai)
    customer_id
    first_name
    last_name
)
```

Now my question is:
lets say I have one customer has many customer_contacts like this

```
customer

 id    name     email
 1     john     john@example.com
```

and customer_contacts is like this (first row)

```
 id    customer_id  first_name   last_name
 1     1            john         doe
 2     1            johnp        pual
```

like this

So here I want to get all the contact details count for the id john. So can some one tell me how to get that?
 
Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. 
Thanks

Comment: use count() and inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Simply join both tables and use `count()` with `group by c.id`  use where to filter records

```
select c.*,
count(*) total_contacts
from customer  c
left join customer_contacts  cc on(c.id = cc.customer_id)
group by c.id
```

### [`Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eebe1/2)

Answer (score 0):

If the id is already known (as suggested by the question, it would be a plain

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from customer_contacts
    WHERE customer_contacts.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to know the number of contactacs for the customer John, right?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM customer cus INNER JOIN customer_contacts con ON cus.id = con.customer_id
WHERE cus.name = 'john'
```

Nevertheless, It would be better if you know the id of John. Your query would be this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM customer_contacts
WHERE customer_id = 1
```